# Replace all URLs in SQL Server table column which contains html data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table column which contains html contents with links in format `href="/page/random_id1/random_id2"`.

Here `random_id1` is a guid and `random_id2` is a slug. Now i would like to run a sql query which can replace all href values by converting them to `href="/page/random_id2"`.

Notice here, i'm removing `random_id1` part from every herf.

Here's a sample query:

```
select top 1 id, htmlcode from tenantpage;

03781776-5f64-4c59-a6f7-5873e0b9f128
<div>test</div><a href="/page/54171776-1f64-4c56-b6f9-7140e0b9fcs1/read-article1">Link</a><div>something else <span>test <a href="/page/32151776-1f64-4c56-b6f9-7120e0b9f012/read-article1-test">Link</a></span></div><a href="/page/76231758-0f69-0c56-x6f5-7120e0b9f01a/best-answers">Link</a>
```

I don't know if this is possible, if possible please help here.

Comment: Is it always structured exactly that way: href="/node1/node2/node3"?

Comment: Take a look at substring. Posting some sample data would be a HUGE help.

Comment: Exaclty as @SeanLange said, just use the Replace. And you can write a good regex that focus on what you want.

Comment: If the column in question is a big blob with an entire HTML file (not just one `href`), and `random_id1` is not a constant, then you can't do this (efficiently) in T-SQL. It has no support for fancy stuff like regex replacements. Solutions that use XML trickery as an intermediate will be especially prone to breaking when HTML input is used. Do yourself a favor and use some solid client code with an equally solid HTML library (like HTML Agility, or anything else compatible with your stack).

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: @JeroenMostert HTMLAgility is another approach which i planned to try next. Because i noticed we can use regex in t-sql i thought to try out this first.

Comment: The "regex" you speak of in T-SQL is **not** RegEx.  And it won't easily allow you to achieve what you want.  I agree with doing it in a client-side app, you'll save yourself a world of trouble (but probably find a bunch of broken HTML to clean up while you're at it ;)